# Button clicked on a page, after successful validation another page has to be opened and a success notification is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring

I have a requirement where I'm using spring, thymleaf, jQuery.
I mapped appropriately in spring controller and binded the form data using thymleaf.
upon entering form data and clicking save button in edit page, after satisfying server side validations, edited preview should be displayed. 
while displaying this preview page, a success notification on top right corner has to be displayed.

I was successful till I displayed preview page satisfying all validations. tried to implement the notification using jquery but not succeeded.

this is what my jquery code is: I kept this js in edit page. since save button is in edit page. 
there is no save button on preview page. the below code executes fine but not displaying notification on preivew page.

```
$('#saveEditUser').click(function() {
    UI.handler.notification('success', 'Success Title!', 'This is success message', {timeout: 5000})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem using PHP, is more easy than JQuery.
Is somtheing like this:

```
<?php 
$message = '';

if(isset(['submit'])){
header ("Location: yourpage.extension");
}

else{
$message="ERROR!"
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, But I'm sorry the project doesn't use PHP.. instead angular js can be used.